# Override overlapped method

Tags: c#, .net, cil

Question is very short, but I didn't found a solution.

Assume we have the class hierarchy

```
public abstract class A
{
    public virtual string Print() { return "A"; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public virtual new string Print() { return "B"; }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override string Print() { return "C"; }
}
```

Is it possible to override A.Print in C class? I tried to do it as explicit interface implementation:

```
string A.Print() { return "C"; }
```

but here I get an error:

> 'A' in explicit interface declaration is not an interface

I think it's not possible at all, but would appreciate receiving any additional info

Comment: Your question is tagged both C# and CIL. Do you want to do this in C# or are you open to writing `C` in CIL?

Comment: @svick because I'm not sure if it's possible or not in C# or IL both, so see a Brian's answer. Now you get why I added cil tag to the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't in C#, but you can in IL by using the `.override` keyword to override which vtable slot the method will use. (note: the method name `Namespace.A.Print` is not significant, including the full type name in the method name is just a useful way of avoiding collisions, in the same way as C# does for explicit interface implementations)

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Namespace.C
    extends [x]Namespace.B
{
    .method private hidebysig virtual 
        instance string Namespace.A.Print () cil managed 
    {
        .override method instance string [x]Namespace.A::Print()
        .maxstack 1
        ldstr "C"
        ret
    }
}
```

Comment: For use of IL, +1! Pure badassery :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it out, but you could easily -

```
interface IA
{
  string Print();
}

interface IB
{
  string Print();
}


public abstract class A : IA
{
    IA.Print() { return "A"; }
}

public class B : IB, A
{
    IB.Print() { return "B"; }
}
```